# Differences between using cin.clear();

Tags: c++, cin

```
while(cin.fail()){

    cout<<"Error: Your line is too long.\nPlease enter a shorter line: ";
    cin.clear(cin.good());
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    cin.getline(name, maxCh);
}
```

I'm using `cin.clear(cin.good());` to clear the error flags

But using `cin.clear();` also works?, if I'm calling this function, what good does putting `cin.good()` do?

Comment: You might want to read e.g. these reference pages for [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [`good`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I'm not sure that `std::cin.clear( std::cin.good() )` is
even guaranteed to compile.  `std::cin.good()` returns a `bool`, 
`std::cin.clear()` requires an `std::ios_base::iostate`, and I'm not
sure that there is guaranteed to be a conversion.
(`std::ios_base::iostate` could be an `enum`, for example.)  Second,
even if it compiles, it only does what you want by accident: because you
only execute this code if `std::cin.fail()` is `true`, `std::cin.good()`
will return `false`, which will convert to `0` for all integral types,
and `std::ios_base::goodbit` (which is probably what you want) is
defined to be `0`.  It's also the default argument for the function, so
there's really no point in specifying it.  (`clear` *can* be used to set
bits, but it's very brutal in the way it does so; usually, when you want
to set an error, you'll use `setstate`, which will not reset any
existing errors.)

For what it's worth: I've never found a case where it would be
appropriate to call `std::basic_ios<>::good()`.

Answer (score 1):

If cin.good() returns true then you are actually setting the eofbit (depending on implementation) with your call to clear. Otherwise you are setting it to goodbit.

If you don't call cin.clear with a parameter, then it will use the default which is goodbit.

Comment: `std::cin.good()` can't return `true` in his code, since `std::cin.fail()` has already returned `true`.  And if it did return `true`, who knows what you'd be setting.  It might be the `eofbit` on some implementations, but it could be anything else as well.

Comment: FWIW: `std::cin.clear( std::cin.good() )` doesn't even compile with g++.